# I am new to python, how do i call back multiple specific elements in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list called `persons_data`, from which I want to retrieve the 2nd and 3rd elements.

```
persons_data[2,3]
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-e6c5cdb06feb> in <module>()
----> 1 persons_data[2,3]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Check the official documentation for lists in python. Start by learning how to do basic stuff the right way, this will make your life easier: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to python, this should so what you need:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

part_of_list = my_list[0:2]
```